# emacs 23 and 24 on osx: why does aquamacs-kill-word sometimes delete to end of line?

Tags: emacs, aquamacs

This doesn't happen if I start aquamacs without any customizations. From stepping through the debugger I first see that transient-mark-mode is true. I set it to nil in my .emacs file, and would prefer if it stayed nil, but other code sets it to a non-false value, causing it to kill the region rather than just kill the word.

Sometimes opt-d or opt-backspace deletes the word, but sometimes it goes
to the end or start of the line respectively. I could comment out all the transient-mark-mode stuff out of the code, but I'd prefer either a hook to customize it, or a way of globally saying I never want any region deleted unless I select it with mark and point the old-fashioned way and use something like kill-region to delete it, or it's actually highlighted and then I can use a cua-style way to delete it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using Aquamacs, but you will get a lot more help more quickly if you use a generic version of Emacs built for OSX.  Most people use just plain old Emacs on OSX.

Comment: Agreed, but I've never managed to get the Option key to work like Meta  running plain old emacs in a Terminal window. Got a solution?

Comment: In the preferences of Terminal.app, there is an option that you just check mark.  It is under Settings / Keyboard in the Terminal preferences -- **Use option as meta key**.  The following link contains the barebones Emacs built for OSX:  http://emacsformacosx.com/  (and there are also nightly builds available). Other popular options include homebrew and macports.  The first one, however, has everything neatly packed into one folder called Emacs.app -- the latter two options contain parts in different places on your hard drive and is more difficult to backup and transfer to different computers.

Comment: I didn't know about that distro. Suits my needs much better than the last four versions or so of aquamacs have. It ran fine without any of the problems I've been reporting lately with no extra customization needed. Thanks.

Comment: The builds from http://www.emacsformacosx.com are essentially what you would get if you just ran `./configure --with-ns` when building your own, which requires some other building tools like *autoconf* and *automake*.  The only really useful special feature I am aware of that Aquamacs has (which cannot be configured after the build) is spellcheck using `nsspellchecker`.  After using `aspell` with the generic version of Emacs, I found that I actually prefer selecting spelling options with keyboard choices instead of using the mouse with `nsspellchecker`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem currently solved by moving from aquamacs to emacsformacosx